# What else do I need to do after Symfony deploy?

Tags: symfony

I have just deployed my Symfony app from GitHub to my web server at Simply.com through an FTP Action script.

I'm getting this error when entering the frontend `403 Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this URL. Your request was blocked by the owner of the website.`

I have done the following in order to fix the problem, but I still see the same error.

1. I installed the Apache Symfony pack and added `AddType application/x-httpd-php82 .php` in the top of my .htaccess file in the /app/public/ folder.
2. I created a .bash_profile file in the root of my web server with this code (to make it run PHP 8.2 - which works):

```
PATH=/opt/alt/php82/usr/bin/:$PATH
export PATH
```

3. `composer install`
4. `npm install`

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Check the doc root is correct in your vhost apache config file so it is pointing to the symfony public folder. Then restart/reload apache.